# How to split a value and increment a part using c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
int value = 0;
int day = 0;           
int record = db.Orders.Where(x => x.Order_Date.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
    && x.Order_Date.Value.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
    && x.Order_Date.Value.Day == DateTime.Now.Day).Count();
if (record > 0)
{
    value = int.Parse(db.Orders.OrderByDescending(x => x.Order_Id).Select(y => y.Order_Id).First().ToString());
    value += 1;
}
else
{
    day = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy"));
    value = day + 0001;
}
```

I want to save the order id in `ddmmyysomevalue` like `0501150001` if it is first order.

I do have above code but how to split `0501150001` like `050115` and `0001` and then increment `0002` for the next order and make it `0501150000` thereby `0501150009` to `0501150010` and make the above code meaningful.

Comment: Storing order id as integer will not represent 05 as day - it will be 501150000 not 0501150000. So use string as id or think about different format.

Comment: To compare the dates of two `DateTime` objects you can just compare the values of the `Date` properties. To concatenate numeric values as if they are strings you need to treat them as `string`s. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store value in string.

For number you have to use format like this.

```
int value = 1;
String finalnumber = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy") + value.ToString("0000");
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0000")); // to format number only.
```

// to get as a number

```
long finalnumber = Convert.ToInt64( DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy") + value.ToString("0000"));
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want it to be

Comment: @User You probably want to create string and convert it to int and not 'play' just with integers.

Comment: @Reniuz what in case if it is to be incremented to 0501150002

Comment: @user I am agree with Reniuz.

Comment: Surely it would be simpler to do this using a string formatting approach? See my answer for an example of this.

Comment: @RichardEverett And I guess you downwoted this answer because ...it not using formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Because the code you've shown will always have the same length for each part of the Order Id you can split by length and cast the final part to an integer. Bear in mind this will break if any part of the orderId starts using a different length in future:

```
// get the date part of the string by length
string datePart = orderId.Substring(0, 6);
// get the count part of the string by length and cast to integer
int countPart = Int32.Parse(orderId.Substring(6, 4));
// increment the count
countPart++;
// convert the count back into a string and pad with zeroes to get length 4
string newCount = countPart.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
// combine with the datepart to get the new OrderId
string newOrderId = datePart + newCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction...

```
int existingTodayOrdersCount = db.Orders
    .Where(x => x.Order_Date.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
    .Count();

string newOrderId = string.Format(
    "{0:yyMMdd}{1:0000}",
    DateTime.Now,
    existingTodayOrdersCount + 1);
```

- When comparing two dates you can just call `.Date` on your `DateTime` objects. No need to explicitly compare the year, month and day
- To concatenate numeric values or format a numeric value with leading zeros you need to treat it as a `string`
- The above code uses a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) (`0000`) and a [custom date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) (`yyMMdd`).

Be aware of subtle bugs though...

- What if you already have 9999 orders today?
- What if this code is executed at midnight (could `DateTime.Now` wrap to the next day part way through execution?)
- What if you delete an order record from the database, in which case `newOrderId` might clash with an existing order?